# WPF form using Powershell to get O365 Client Access settings

Tags: wpf, powershell

I'm looking for help for my WPF form script, I'm creating using powershell with WPF form. I am trying to get command output of Powershell exchange online cmdlets when i click submit button, for example Get-CASMailbox. it seems like it's not connecting in the same session or something. If I start up a powershell window and put in the commands to connect then i was able to get the details, however when i tried to run the script and click submit button in the form,nothing is happening. Can anyone help me figure out where I'm having a problem?

Here is the code I'm using

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Confirm:$false -Force
Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationframework, presentationcore
Add-Type -AssemblyName WindowsBase

$wpf = @{ }

Function Connect-ExchangeOnline {
    $msolcred = Get-Credential
    Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
    $Global:Session365 = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri  https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-LiveID/ -Credential $msolcred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
   Import-PSSession $global:Session365 -AllowClobber
   }

[xml]$Form = @" 
  <Window Name="AzureAD"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp5"
    Title="AzureAD Tool" Height="470" Width="800" Topmost="True">
<StackPanel>
    <Grid>
       <Button x:Name="Submit" Content="Submit"  Width="129" Margin="4,6,4,2" FontWeight="Bold" />
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>

</Window>

"@
#Create a form
$Global:xmlReader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $Form
$Global:xmlform = [Windows.Markup.xamlReader]::Load($xmlReader)
$Global:namedNodes = $Form.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'Name')]]")
$Global:namedNodes | ForEach-Object {$wpf.Add($_.Name, 
$xmlform.Findname($_.Name))}

$wpf.Submit.Add_Click({
    Connect-ExchangeOnline
    Get-CASMailbox 
})

$wpf.AzureAD.ShowDialog()
#Get-CASMailbox 
Remove-PSSession -ComputerName outlook.office365.com
```

Comment: Before implementing your WPF structure, does your code work? Do you receive an error?

Comment: yes, no error came, i was able to execute and form was loading. but when i tried to click submit button, no command output was coming.. basically i wanted to get or change CASMailbox settings.. even the exchange online commands seems to be loading, but the commands are not available under submit button.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out that, for some reason when i call the Get-CASMailbox with WPF its not getting any output, but when i add "Get-CASMailbox | out-host" i was able to get it..